# Updating an asmx web service and making changes visible to another project

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I'm working with a website that has an asmx service with methods decorated like so:

```
        [WebMethod(Description = "Search Method for items of type Foo.")]
        [XmlInclude(typeof(SearchResults))]
        public SearchResults[] FooSearch(//.....
```

There is another VS project that has a service reference to this asmx service.  It also has a file named 'Reference.cs' in it with a boilerplate statement at the top that states it is an auto-generated file, etc.  It has interface and partial class definitions like this:

```
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        public partial class MyClass: UserAuthentication {
```

I now need to update the asmx service and add a few new methods.  When I'm done, how can I convey these changes to the other project?  Is it a matter of removing and re-adding the service reference, or do I need to run the asmx's code-behind file through a wsdl compiler of some sort, and add the resulting file(s) to the project?  I've never done this before so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a matter of removing and re-adding the service reference

That's the simplest way to do it for sure.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the 'Reference' file regenerated automatically when adding the service again?

Comment: Yes it is, that's really what adding a service reference does, it downloads all the necessary metadata and generates code that creates the proxies and classes and such.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio will do the work for you.  Just remove the old one and point to the new one at the URL and your done.